# gunicorn: command not found

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gunicorn

I get `gunicorn: command not found` when I run my Docker image. And when I shell into image and run it manually I get the same error.

However, the output of `pip install gunicorn` confirms it is installed:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: gunicorn in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (20.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from gunicorn) (58.1.0)
```

Here are the files to build this image:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.10.5-alpine

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN adduser -D appuser

USER appuser

WORKDIR /home/appuser/

COPY --chown=appuser:appuser requirements.txt .

RUN python -m pip install --user --no-cache-dir --disable-pip-version-check --requirement requirements.txt

COPY --chown=appuser:appuser . .

ENTRYPOINT [ "./entrypoint.sh" ]
```

**requirements.txt**

```
django==4.0.6
psycopg2-binary==2.9.3
gunicorn==20.1.0
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
gunicorn project.wsgi:application --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 --workers=4 --timeout=300 --log-level=debug --log-file=-
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `RUN pip install` as root, without the `--user` option.

If you run [`pip install --user`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-user), it installs packages into [`~/.local`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#site.USER_BASE).  In Docker the `$HOME` environment variable isn't usually defined, so this will install them into `/.local`.  If you looked inside the built image, you'd probably find a runnable `/.local/bin/gunicorn`, but that `/.local/bin` directory isn't on the `$PATH`.

Typical use in Docker is to install Python packages into the "system" Python; the Docker image itself is isolation from other Pythons.  This will put the `*.py` files into somewhere like `/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages`, and the `gunicorn` executable will be in `/usr/local/bin`, which is on the standard `$PATH`.

```bash
FROM python:3.10.5-alpine
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RUN adduser -D appuser
WORKDIR /home/appuser/
# but do not change USER yet

COPY --chown=appuser:appuser requirements.txt .

# Without --user option
RUN python -m pip install --no-cache-dir --disable-pip-version-check --requirement requirements.txt

# Change USER _after_ RUN pip install
USER appuser

COPY --chown=appuser:appuser . .
ENTRYPOINT [ "./entrypoint.sh" ]
```